# Converting Cucumber Java Project to Maven Project and Running in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, cucumber, testng

I have converted my java project (which is built using cucumber framework) to Maven Project.
Am not able to use Sure Fire Plugin , since my folder structure is not as this format "src/test/java"

My folder structure is testng xml consisting information of cucumber runner file , now my aim is to trigger this testng xml in jenkins.

am aware of executing testng xml from command prompt , but to do that , we need to have lib folder in place. Since am using Maven , i dont have local lib folder.
Can someone please suggest , what to do in this case ? (don't want to change the folder structure)

Thanks in advance

Comment: My advice would be to create a local maven repository either on the build machine or another machine with a shared network folder.  Jenkins will then have the libraries required to build.  Alternatively, you could try to get SureFire plugin to work.  I'm almost certain you can reconfigure the default configuration to use your project structure.

Comment: @Neil : Hi Neil , Thanks so much for your response , Appreciate !! , Can you please elaborate on "reconfigure the default configuration to use your project structure using SureFire plugin"   , any idea how can i achieve this ? like , where to change the default settings of SureFire Plugin ?

Comment: I see that Krishnan has found the doc page, but for reference, it is [this](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testClassesDirectory).  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first bring in the required dependencies for your CLASSPATH, by adding 
`<dependency>` entries into your pom file.

In short, you would need to add atleast the below ones

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- ignoring older version of testng -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <!-- Remove the scope tag, if you have some TestNG listener code residing in src/main/java -->
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now add the below entries to tell Maven where your test classes reside and where your test resources reside.

```
<build>
    <!-- test sources represents the folder where in your classes that contain @Test methods reside-->
    <testSourceDirectory></testSourceDirectory>
    <!-- test resources represents the folder which contains your .feature files, your .suite xml etc-->
    <testResources></testResources>
</build>
```

For more details on how to tweak surefire plugin's behavior refer [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html).

Comment: Awesome Thanks Krishnan ,  <testSourceDirectory></testSourceDirectory> , actually in my framework i dint mention any @ Test methods , When i run the cucumber feature file , it will directly pick up the method from step Definition. So my setup consists as below : Feature Folder which contains all the dot feature files, runnerPackage   consists of runnerClass consisting of cucumber options and path to Feature folder , then TestNG XML - consisting of package name with JUNIT as true . So with this kind of setup , can i ignore testSourceDir and  try with only <testResources></testResources> ??

Comment: According to my setup , i have to trigger either my runner file or testng suite xml file in jenkins , but as i mentioned there is problem for triggering xml using command line since i have to provide lib folder which is not possible now because i converted to Maven , is there a way to trigger my runner file using sure fire plugin ?

Comment: The moment you add `<dependency>` Maven starts managing things for you. So you dont need the `lib` folder. You merely kick start your execution by running `mvn clean test`. This is the same command you would use for running your tests using maven either on the command prompt or via Jenkins.

Comment: Sorry for asking too many questions :) , i have multiple runner package , each runner package consists of each java class , each java class will run on depending on tag provided in cucumber options , now for this ? how can i run my required runner using mvn clean test ? i am assuming this command will run all the scripts in the project.

Comment: Assuming you create a Runner class such as [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-calculator-testng/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/calculator/RunCukesTest.java) you would merely use `mvn clean test -Dtest=RunCukesTest`. So for every new such runner, you would create a different RunCukesTest class and refer to it in the `-Dtest` JVM argument.

Comment: You don't have to exclude testng from cucumber because maven is supposed to take the version you specified.

Comment: Just an additional question i have , created new maven project in eclipse ,now everything is fine when i run from Jenkins , but when run individually single cucumber feature file , latest code is not executing , event i comment some steps from scenario , they are still running , i don't think eclipse is building the latest code , any suggestions ?

Comment: I have kept all the class files in src/main/java and feature files in src/test/resources  , nothing is present in src/test/java

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the code to see what is going on. I would suggest that you create a new question for that and include all details along with screenshots (if applicable) to elaborate your problem.

Comment: Ok.. Cool , i will do that !